# How to add each item from a list to dictionaries from another list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following lists:

A list of dictionaries,

```
>>> print(*item_cart, sep='\n')
{'Item #': 1, 'Price ': 3.99, 'Quantity': 10, 'Name': 'Porcupine'}
{'Item #': 2, 'Price ': 2.99, 'Quantity': 3, 'Name': 'Muffin2'}
```

and a list of values,

```
>>> print(specific_item_total)
[39.99, 8.97]
```

I want to combine the two lists, to create a new list `receipt`:

```
>>> print(*receipt, sep='\n')
{'Item #': 1, 'Price ': 3.99, 'Quantity': 10, 'Name': 'Porcupine', "Total": 39.99}
{'Item #': 2, 'Price ': 2.99, 'Quantity': 3, 'Name': 'Muffin2', "Total": 8.97}
```

Obviously, I would need to append `specific_item_total` into `item_cart`, and make a `for` loop to go through each item, and add a new key and value for each already existing dictionary. How would this be done?

Comment: That's not a list. There's no `[]` around it.

Comment: Don't write `print(item_cart)` if that's not what you actually used to print the two lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-do-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip`:

```py
item_cart = [{'Item #': 1, 'Price ': 3.99, 'Quantity': 10, 'Name': 'Porcupine'}, {'Item #': 2, 'Price ': 2.99, 'Quantity': 3, 'Name': 'Muffin2'}]
specific_item_total = [39.99, 8.97]

output = [{**dct, 'Total': total} for dct, total in zip(item_cart, specific_item_total)]

print(output)
# [{'Item #': 1, 'Price ': 3.99, 'Quantity': 10, 'Name': 'Porcupine', 'Total': 39.99},
#  {'Item #': 2, 'Price ': 2.99, 'Quantity': 3, 'Name': 'Muffin2', 'Total': 8.97}]
```

Comment: What is `**dct`?

Comment: @py_coder1019 That's unpacking: https://peps.python.org/pep-0448/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [new python dictionary merge](https://pythontic.com/containers/dictionary/merge%20operator) syntax, together with the [`zip` function](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/):

```
list(c | {"Total": t} for c, t in zip(item_cart, specific_item_total))
```

Comment: aka [PEP 584](https://peps.python.org/pep-0584/).